# Batch file to find all Access Databases

Tags: batch-file

I need help creating a Batch file that looks in a file dir for all files that have .accdb, then writes the file name and full path to a text file. First time doing this so the more detail the better. I would like to understand this so I can create other batch files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will search from the current directory and below:

```
dir *.accdb /s /b /a-d >file.txt
```

This is another form of the command to search from a particular folder and write to a file in another location:

```
dir "c:\folder\*.accdb" /s /b /a-d >"d:\other folder\file.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be what your looking for. Change "Database DIR" to the directory you want to search and change c:\OUTPUT.txt to what you want the output location and filetype to be.

```
@echo off
SET FILEPATH="Database DIR"  
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir /b "%FILEPATH%" *.accdb') DO (
echo %FILEPATH%%%G >> c:\OUTPUT.txt
)
```