# Find all Access databases, and Compact and Repair

Tags: batch-file, ms-access

I'm trying to find all Access databases in a directory and Compact and Repair each without opening Access each time. I found the following article explaining how to find them and write to a file:
[Batch file to find all Access Databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25366356/batch-file-to-find-all-access-databases), but ideally I'd like to just find them and compact without writing to a file.

I have searched how to call the `/compact` command line functionality, but I don't know how to do it on the databases I find. Can a `.bat` file be written to do this? Something like:

`@echo off`

`"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\MSACCESS.EXE"` `"C:\Databases\ /s" *.accdb` `/compact`

Any help with the syntax is very much appreciated.

Comment: http://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html is probably the easiest way.

Comment: Or a standard [`for` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html)...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider using Access' dedicated [CompactRepair](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193242.aspx) method which you can run in VBA (inside an Access database or outside like in an Excel macro). The thing to note is Compact & Repair actually creates a copy of existing database and replaces it with original, so some file handling is needed.

**VBA** *(inside MSAccess.exe)*

```vb
Sub RunCompactDBs()
    Dim path As String
    Dim accfile As Variant

    path = "C:\Databases\"
    accfile = Dir(path & "*.accdb", vbDirectory)

    Do While Len(accfile) > 0
        bkfile = Replace(accfile, ".accdb", "_bk.accdb")

        ' CREATE COMPACTED BACKUP
        Application.CompactRepair path & accfile, path & bkfile, False      
        ' COPY TO ORIGINAL PATH
        FileCopy path & bkfile, path & accfile     
        ' DESTROY COMPACTED BACKUP
        Kill path & bkfile                    

        accfile = Dir
    Loop

    Set accApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

**VBA** *(outside MSAccess.exe)*

```vb
Sub RunCompactDBs()
    Dim path As String
    Dim accfile As Variant
    Dim accApp As Object

    Set accApp = CreateObject("Access.Application")

    path = "C:\Databases\"
    accfile = Dir(path & "*.accdb", vbDirectory)

    Do While Len(accfile) > 0
        bkfile = Replace(accfile, ".accdb", "_bk.accdb")

        accApp.CompactRepair path & accfile, path & bkfile, False      

        FileCopy path & bkfile, path & accfile                           
        Kill path & bkfile

        accfile = Dir
    Loop

    Set accApp = Nothing        
End Sub
```

---

And there's no reason to stick with VBA. Any language that can make a COM interface to the Access object library can run the compact and repair procedure like open-source languages:

**Python**

```py
import os, glob, shutil
import win32com.client

# LAUNCH ACCESS APP
oApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Access.Application")

for file in glob.glob("C:\\Databases\\*.accdb"):       
    bkfile = file.replace(".accdb", "_bk.accdb")

    oApp.CompactRepair(file, bkfile, False)

    shutil.copyfile(bkfile, file)
    os.remove(bkfile)

oApp = None
```

**R**

```r
library(RDCOMClient)

# LAUNCH ACCESS APP
oApp = COMCreate("Access.Application")

accfiles <- list.files(path="C:\\Databases\\", pattern="\\.accdb", full.names=TRUE)

for (file in accfiles){      
  bkfile = sub(".accdb", "_bk.accdb", file)

  oApp$CompactRepair(file, bkfile, FALSE)

  file.copy(bkfile, file, overwrite = TRUE)
  file.remove(bkfile)      
}

oApp <- NULL
gc()
```

**PHP**

```php
# LAUNCH ACCESS APP
$acc = new COM("Access.Application", NULL, CP_UTF8) or Die ("Did not instantiate Access");

foreach (glob("C:\\Databases\\*.accdb") as $file) {            
    $bkfile = str_replace(".accdb", "_bk.accdb", $file);

    $acc->Application->CompactRepair($file, $bkfile, false);

    copy($bkfile, $file);
    unlink($bkfile);    
}

$acc = NULL;
unset($acc);
```

Comment: Thank you for the options @Parfait! I'll give them a try and see what works best. Will this also check subfolders or only the directory specified?

Comment: How to modify compact and repair for a specific file?

Comment: @Jadeye, simply follow any above solution without `for` loop.