# Compact and Repair all Access databases in a directory using Powershell

Tags: powershell, ms-access, scripting

I am looking to find a way to compact and repair all the Access databases in a certain directory using Powershell via a script.

The VBA codes below work, but need one for Powershell:

[Find all Access databases, and Compact and Repair](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39089467/2144390)

I am new to Powershell so will be grateful for the assistance.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access

$rootfolder = 'c:\some\folder'

$createlog = $true # change to false if no log desired

$access = New-Object -ComObject access.application
$access.Visible = $false
$access.AutomationSecurity = 1

Get-ChildItem -Path $rootfolder -File -Filter *.accdb -Recurse -PipelineVariable file | ForEach-Object {

    $newname = Join-Path $file.Directory ("{0}_compacted{1}" -f $file.BaseName,$file.Extension)

    $message = @"
    Current file: {0}
    Output file: {1}
"@ -f $file.FullName,$newname

    Write-Host $message -ForegroundColor Cyan

    $access.CompactRepair($file.fullname,$newname,$createlog)
}

$access.Quit()
```

This will output each compacted database as the name of the original file with _compacted appended to the name (before the extension.) I have tested this in every way except actually compacting databases.

**Edit**

Regarding your comment, a few minor changes should achieve the desired result. Keep in mind that this will put all new files in the same folder. This may not be an issue for your case but if there are duplicate file names you will have problems.

```
$rootfolder  = 'c:\some\folder'
$destination = 'c:\some\other\folder'
$todaysdate  = get-date -format '_dd_MM_yyyy'

Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access

$createlog = $true # change to false if no log desired

$access = New-Object -ComObject access.application
$access.Visible = $false
$access.AutomationSecurity = 1

Get-ChildItem -Path $rootfolder -File -Filter *.accdb -Recurse -PipelineVariable file | ForEach-Object {

    $newname = Join-Path $destination ("{0}$todaysdate{1}" -f $file.BaseName,$file.Extension)

    $message = @"
    Current file: {0}
    Output file: {1}
"@ -f $file.FullName,$newname

    Write-Host $message -ForegroundColor Cyan

    $access.CompactRepair($file.fullname,$newname,$createlog)
}

$access.Quit()
```

Comment: This works, Thanks! I would also like to tweak this so that backups go in a separate folder with the date on the end "db1_03_03_2021" and the compacted file to remain in the current folder without the "_compacted" in the filename.

Comment: Great. If it was helpful consider clicking the upvote. If it solved your issue, consider accepting it as the answer. This will help future readers. You can always change the accepted answer later if a better answer comes along. The tweaks you mention are quite easy to accomplish and are a very frequent topic here and elsewhere on the web. Give it a shot and provide some details if you run into issues.

Comment: You are welcome. I hope you have a great day.

Comment: This is very close to what I was after. Thanks again! I am trying to dissect the code to understand it further. Other than Google, what resources would you recommend?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229513/discussion-between-tifsta-and-doug-maurer).